# make TextField accept only numbers and + sign in flutter

Tags: flutter, format, textfield

I want the field to allow the entry of numbers and the + sign only but all I could do was make the field allow the entry of numbers only and I couldn't make it accept the + sign

here is my code

```
TextField(
      inputFormatters: [
        FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
          RegExp(
            "[0-9]",
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
TextField(
        inputFormatters: [
          FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
          RegExp(
            r'^\+?\d*',
          ),
        ),],
      )
```

This will accept an optional + sign at the begining and the rest are numbers. The same as international phone numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
  TextField(
            
         keyboardType:TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal:true,signed:true),
                        inputFormatters: [
                          
                        
           FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp('[0-9.,]+')),
                        ],
        )
```

,

just add this.

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't let me add +